# How to add extra level in Meteor concatenates js and css path

Tags: meteor

After compile and build the Meteor application for production. All the js and css files have been minified and concatenated as one js or css file like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/668709f5b029ed3db7692654ebb3c305ae2d1b1a.css?meteor_css_resource=true">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/327435ecda451157c3d8a0af70c6172f58fe77cf.js?meteor_js_resource=true"></script>
```

These files' URL start with root. My question is: How to add extra level in it? the expected result should be:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/a_extra_level_here/668709f5b029ed3db7692654ebb3c305ae2d1b1a.css?meteor_css_resource=true">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/a_extra_level_here/327435ecda451157c3d8a0af70c6172f58fe77cf.js?meteor_js_resource=true"></script>
```